# Vue.js + Element UI: How to handle HTTP request errors commonly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource, element-ui

I'd like to centralize HTTP request errors that can occours when I call any http request method like (`$http.post`, `$http.delete`, etc...) using `vue-resource`.

I know I can handle errors for any single request like following:

```
this.$http.post(restUrl, payload).then(onSuccess, onFailure);
```

But, I guess if I can define and set the `onFailure` callback function for any HTTP requests.
I'd like to handle any http errors at application-level or something similar.

My goal is to show a generic toast message when an HTTP request fails.

Any kind of help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Do you use `axios` or `vue-resource` (or anything else)?

Comment: I have `vue-resource` in `main.js` and now I understand what's it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the concept that you like to use are `interceptors`.
In `vue-resource` you can define them for `request` and `response`.
An example for a interceptor:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {

  // modify request ...

  // stop and return response
  next(request.respondWith(body, {
    status: 404,
    statusText: 'Not found'
  }));
});
```

Comment: If that solves or answers your question, I would appreciate when you mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [C Sharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1487681/c-sharper) for the very good start point.
I've wrote here my final solution for posterity.

I've checked the `response` status in the interceptor and if it isn't `ok`, it will show a message to end-user, using the `$alert()` function.

Here the code:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {
    next((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            let message = "<summary>Unexpected error</summary><details>Error: " + response.status + " " + response.url + "</details>";
            this.$alert(message, 'Error', {
                "type" : "error",
                "dangerouslyUseHTMLString" : "true"
            });
        }
        return response;
    });
}
```